# How can I execute a jar and capture the output?

Tags: objective-c

With Objective-C in a cocoa app, I want to execute a jar with some arguments and capture the output (stdout). How can I do this?

Comment: How is the output output? To the standard out? or to a file?

Comment: It is output via standard out.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the jar using `NSTask`. From `NSTask` you can get an `NSPipe` or `NSFileHandle` that represents the stdout of the launched process.